# `document.body.appendChild(elem);` appends to the end of the html body. How to place in specific place in the body?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

[The following code](http://jsfiddle.net/r37yY/1/) creates a text input field AFTER the `Hey girls!` paragraph when pressing on the `push` button:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function func()
{
var elem=document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(elem);
elem.setAttribute('type','text');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hey guys!<p>
<input type="button" value="push" onclick="func()"/>
<script>
func();
</script>
<p>Hey girls!<p>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I make sure the text input fields are created before the `Hey girls!` paragraph and after the `Hey guys!` paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a job for `HTMLElement.prototype.insertBefore`.

Synopsis: *parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement);*

Example:

```
document.body.insertBefore( elem, document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1] );
```

Since you haven't any *ID* or *classname* for your paragraph node here, I just referenced that with `.getElementsByTagName`. Would make things easier if you have a more accurate query possibility.

Ref.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore). You only need to obtain a reference to the "Hey girls!" paragraph. In your case, you could select the second paragraph in the body, or maybe the element after the only input in the body - or you use an id. Example:

```
function func() {
    var elem = document.createElement("input");
    elem.setAttribute('type','text');
    var ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    if (ps.length < 2)
        return; // abort! we didn't find our element
    var p = ps[1];      
    document.body.insertBefore(elem, p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the appendChild on a specific parent element, not on the body.